# Degree of cyclotomic extension of local field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a local field and let $L$ be a degree $n$ separable extension. Let $\kappa_K$ and $\kappa_L$ be the associated residue fields, which satisfy $|\kappa_K| = q$ and $[\kappa_L:\kappa_K]=f$. By Hensel's lemma, we know that $L$ contains a primitive $q^f$-$1$st root of unity $\zeta$, and that $\kappa_K(\bar{\zeta}) = \kappa_L$. Therefore, $\kappa_L=\kappa_{K(\zeta)}$, so $[\kappa_{K(\zeta)}:\kappa] = f$. I'd like to prove that $K(\zeta)$ is unramified, which boils down to proving $[K(\zeta):K]=f$. I feel like Hensel's lemma should explain this part too, but I'm sort of stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not sure what the problem is. You have $K\subset L$, and between them you have the maximal unramified extension of $K$ in $L$, call it $K^{\text u}$. You know that the residue field extensions $f^L_K=f^{K^{\text u}}_K=[\kappa_L:\kappa_K]$, while for the ramification degrees, $e^L_K=e^L_{K^{\text u}}$, i.e. the top layer is totally ramified, the bottom is totally unramified. You have to use multiplicativity of both the residue field degrees $f^?_?$ and the ramification indices $e^?_?$.

If this isn’t enough for you, get back to me in a comment, and I’ll try to fill in any missing details.

**EDIT — Addendum**:
You have asked why, when adjoining a primitive $q^f$-th root of unity to $K$ you get the maximal unramified extension of $K$ in $L$. Let’s see how this works:

I’ll change your notation slightly, letting the residue-class fields be $\kappa$ and $\lambda$, so that my $\kappa$ is your $\kappa_K$, and my $\lambda$ is your $\kappa_L$. Now, by definition, the residue-field extension degree of $L$ over $K$, which we’re denoting $f$, is $[\lambda:\kappa]$. Let $\zeta_0$ be a primitive ($q^f-1$)-th root of unity
in $\lambda$, say with minimal $\kappa$-polynomial $\varphi(X)\in\kappa[X]$. I’m going to call $q^f=Q$, for convenience.

Now lift $\varphi$ to any monic polynomial $\Phi(X)\in K[X]$; this is still $K$-irreducible. Since $\varphi$ splits into linear factors over $\lambda$, one of these being $X-\zeta_0$,
Hensel tells us that $\Phi(X)$ also splits into linear factors over $L$, one of these being $X-\xi$ with $\xi\mapsto\zeta_0\in\lambda$, but of course $\xi$ need not be a root of unity at all.

Nonetheless, $\xi^{q^f}\equiv\xi\mod{\mathfrak M}$, where $\mathfrak M$ is the maximal ideal in the integers of $L$. I’ll ask you to consider the sequence
$$\xi, \xi^Q, (\xi^Q)^Q=\xi^{Q^2},\xi^{Q^3},\cdots$$
which you easily show is $\mathfrak M$-adically convergent, all of the terms being congruent to $\xi$ modulo $\mathfrak M$. And of course the limit is a ($Q-1$)-th root of unity reducing to $\zeta_0$ in $\lambda$.
This limit is what I’ll call $\zeta$; it’s a primitive such root. Its
minimal polynomial is congruent to $\Phi$ modulo $\mathfrak M$, that is, it reduces to $\varphi(X)$, and it’s still irreducible.

Putting it all together, what do we have? $K(\zeta)=K(\xi)$ is of degree $f$ over $K$, unramified since its residue-field degree is equal to its vector-space degree. And certainly there is no larger unramified extension
of $K$ in $L$. So I think that you have your maximal unramified extension, generated by a root of unity of the right type.

Comment: I am eventually trying to prove the existence of $K^\text{u}$. I'd like to say that we can take $K^{\text{u}}=K(\zeta)$. First I have to prove $K(\zeta)$ is unramified.

Comment: See what you think of the addendum, @confused_wallet.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still not understanding -- how are you calculating the degree $[K[\zeta]:K]$?

Comment: Let’s see: We know that $\zeta\in K[\xi]$, so that $[K(\zeta):K]\le f$. But $\zeta$ reduces to $\zeta_0$ modulo $\mathfrak M$, and therefore it can not satisfy a polynomial of lower degree than $f$: otherwise $\zeta_0$ would. So its degree over $K$ must be $f$.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm understanding now. I was forgetting the minimal polynomial of $\xi$ over $K$ has degree $f$.